# Error when installing package in Octave-online

Tags: octave

I want to install the image package in Octave-online.net, but when I tried it, it gave me an error message. I am on a MacBook Air 2013 (if that's important), on macOS 11.7.2 .

I have tried to install Octave on my laptop and that didn't work, so I'm trying it with the online version.

I wrote

```
pkg install -forge image
```

and expected it to install the package, but instead it gave me the following error message:

```
error: get_forge_pkg: could not read version number from package's page
error: called from
    get_forge_pkg at line 55 column 7
    get_forge_download at line 32 column 14
    pkg at line 538 column 31
```

Does somebody know how to fix this or another way to install the package?

Thanks so much!

Comment: If I were to run an online Octave, I wouldn’t allow people to install packages. I also would have standard packages like `image` already installed. Did you try just loading the package?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried `pkg load image` and it loaded the package. No need to install it yourself.